I am doing a Spring - Angular ecommerce and I have a problem with the add product to cart api
in google console I have this problem
POST http://localhost:8080/api/customer/cart 409 (Conflict)
dashboard.component.ts:54 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: _HttpHeaders, status: 409, statusText: 'OK', url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/customer/cart', ok: false, …}
And then when i click add to cart in other product i have this problem
dashboard.component.ts:54
POST http://localhost:8080/api/customer/cart 403 (Forbidden)
dashboard.component.ts:54 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: _HttpHeaders, status: 403, statusText: 'OK', url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/customer/cart', ok: false, …}
and in the backend and in the backend this error appears:
WARN 24432 : SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
ERROR 24432 : Duplicate entry '1' for key 'cart_items.UKshvxaq4vg05f3q75fnnel0klb'
ERROR 24432 : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement [Duplicate entry '1' for key 'cart_items.UKshvxaq4vg05f3q75fnnel0klb'] [insert into cart_items (order_id,price,product_id,quantity,user_id) values (?,?,?,?,?)]; SQL [insert into cart_items (order_id,price,product_id,quantity,user_id) values (?,?,?,?,?)]; constraint [cart_items.UKshvxaq4vg05f3q75fnnel0klb]] with root cause
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'cart_items.UKshvxaq4vg05f3q75fnnel0klb'
CartItems.java

@Entity
@Data
public class CartItems {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private Long price;
    
    private Long quantity;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Product product;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private User user;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Order order;
    
    public CartItemsDto getCartDto() {
        CartItemsDto cartItemsDto = new CartItemsDto();
        cartItemsDto.setId(id);
        cartItemsDto.setPrice(price);
        cartItemsDto.setProductId(product.getId());
        cartItemsDto.setQuantity(quantity);
        cartItemsDto.setUserId(user.getId());
        cartItemsDto.setProductName(product.getName());
        cartItemsDto.setReturnedImg(product.getImg());
        
        return cartItemsDto;
    }
}

AddProductToCartDto


@Data
public class AddProductInCartDto {
    
    private Long userId;
    private Long productId;
}


CartItemsRepository

@Repository
public interface CartItemsRepository extends JpaRepository<CartItems, Long> {

    Optional<CartItems> findByProductIdAndOrderIdAndUserId (Long productId, Long orderId, Long userId);
}


CartService

public interface CartService {

    ResponseEntity<?> addProductToCart(AddProductInCartDto addProductInCartDto);
    
    OrderDto getCardByUserId(Long userId);
}

CartServiceImpl

@Service
public class CartServiceImpl implements CartService{
    
    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private CartItemsRepository cartItemsRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    
    public ResponseEntity<?> addProductToCart(AddProductInCartDto addProductInCartDto){
        Order activeOrder = orderRepository.findByUserIdAndOrderStatus(addProductInCartDto.getUserId(), OrderStatus.Pending);
        Optional<CartItems> optionalCartItems = cartItemsRepository.findByProductIdAndOrderIdAndUserId
                (addProductInCartDto.getProductId(), activeOrder.getId(), addProductInCartDto.getUserId());
        
        if(optionalCartItems.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(null);
        }else {
            Optional<Product> optionalProduct = productRepository.findById(addProductInCartDto.getProductId());
            Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findById(addProductInCartDto.getUserId());
            
            if(optionalProduct.isPresent() && optionalUser.isPresent()) {
                CartItems cart = new CartItems();
                cart.setProduct(optionalProduct.get());
                cart.setPrice(optionalProduct.get().getPrice());
                cart.setQuantity(1L);
                cart.setUser(optionalUser.get());
                cart.setOrder(activeOrder);
                
                CartItems updatedCart = cartItemsRepository.save(cart);
                
                activeOrder.setTotalAmount(activeOrder.getTotalAmount() + cart.getPrice());
                activeOrder.setAmount(activeOrder.getAmount() + cart.getPrice());
                activeOrder.getCartItems().add(cart);
                
                orderRepository.save(activeOrder);
                
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(cart.getId());
                
            }else {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("User or product not found");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public OrderDto getCardByUserId(Long userId) {
        Order activeOrder = orderRepository.findByUserIdAndOrderStatus(userId, OrderStatus.Pending);
        List<CartItemsDto> cartItemsDtoList = activeOrder.getCartItems().stream().map(CartItems::getCartDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
        OrderDto orderDto = new OrderDto();
        orderDto.setAmount(activeOrder.getAmount());
        orderDto.setId(activeOrder.getId());
        orderDto.setOrderStatus(activeOrder.getOrderStatus());
        orderDto.setDiscount(activeOrder.getDiscount());
        orderDto.setTotalAmount(activeOrder.getTotalAmount());
        orderDto.setCartItems(cartItemsDtoList);
        
        return orderDto;
    }
} 

CartController

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/customer")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CartController {

    private final CartService cartService;
    
    @PostMapping("/cart")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addProductToCart(@RequestBody AddProductInCartDto addProductInCartDto){
        return cartService.addProductToCart(addProductInCartDto);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/cart/{userId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getCartByUserId(@PathVariable Long userId){
        OrderDto orderDto = cartService.getCardByUserId(userId);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(orderDto);
    }
}

WebSecurityConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {
    
    private final JwtRequestFilter authFilter;
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf
                        .disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/authenticate", "/sign-up", "/order/**", "/api/admin/category",
                                "/api/admin", "/api/admin/product", "/api/admin/products", "/api/admin/search/{name}",
                                "/api/admin/product/{productId}", "/api/customer/search/{name}", "/api/customer/products",
                                "/api/customer/cart")
                        .permitAll())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/api/**")
                        .authenticated()) 
                .sessionManagement(management -> management
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(authFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
                
    }
    
    @Bean PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception{
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}

AND THAT'S WHAT I CALLED IT IN ANGULAR
customer.service.ts
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserStorageService } from '../../services/storage/user-storage.service';

const BASIC_URL = "http://localhost:8080/"

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllProducts(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(BASIC_URL + 'api/customer/products', {
      headers: this.createAuthorizationHeader(),
    })
  }

  getAllProductsByName(name:any): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(BASIC_URL + `api/customer/search/${name}`, {
      headers: this.createAuthorizationHeader(),
    })
  }

  addToCart(productId:any): Observable<any>{
    const cartDto = {
      productId : productId,
      userId: UserStorageService.getUserId()
    }
    return this.http.post(BASIC_URL + 'api/customer/cart', cartDto ,{
      headers: this.createAuthorizationHeader(),
    })
  }

  private createAuthorizationHeader(): HttpHeaders{
    return new HttpHeaders().set(
      'Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserStorageService.getToken()
    )
  }
}

dashboard.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomerService } from '../../services/customer.service';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrl: './dashboard.component.scss'
})
export class DashboardComponent {

  products: any[] = [];
  searchProductForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private customerService: CustomerService, 
    private fb:FormBuilder,
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar)
    {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getAllProducts();
    this.searchProductForm = this.fb.group({
      title: [null, [Validators.required]]
    })
  }


  getAllProducts(){
    this.products = [];
    this.customerService.getAllProducts().subscribe(res =>{
      res.forEach(element => {
        element.processedImg = 'data:/image/jpeg;base64,' + element.byteImg
        this.products.push(element);
      });
      console.log(this.products)
    })
  }

  submitForm(){
    this.products = [];
    const title = this.searchProductForm.get('title')!.value;
    this.customerService.getAllProductsByName(title).subscribe(res =>{
      res.forEach(element => {
        element.processedImg = 'data:/image/jpeg;base64,' + element.byteImg
        this.products.push(element);
      });
      console.log(this.products)
    })
  }

  addToCart(id:any){
    this.customerService.addToCart(id).subscribe(res =>{
      this.snackBar.open('Product added to the cart successfully', 'Close', { duration: 5000 })
    })
  }
}

